# Set interval works only first time. Is there any solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to run the function continuously. But it only works first time properly. Is there any solution for working this function continuously?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(() => {
    $('#open-band').trigger('click');
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#close-band').trigger('click');
    }, 50000);
  }, 15000);
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this code to do? A working example in a snippet would help a lot here.

Comment: There’s no way to tell why this code doesn’t work without seeing the HTML that the selectors select.

Comment: Your `setTimeout` is substantially longer than your `setInterval` timeout - perhaps you meant `5000` for the close timeout.  As it is, it will appear that the close isn't working.   Not sure what "it only works first time *properly*" means though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 
hi, I want to trigger a button to show a div after 15 secs when the page is loaded, and 50 secs later another trigger for closing the div. & I want to run this continuously.

Comment: Do you mean: after 15s show, wait 50s hide, wait 15s show, wait 50s hide?   You can't run "when page is loaded" "continuously" as the page only loads once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the comment under the question explaining your goal:

> I want to trigger a button to show a div after 15 secs when the page is loaded, and 50 secs later another trigger for closing the div. & I want to run this continuously

I would suggest that you chain `setTimeout()` calls instead of using `setInterval()` which will cause the events to overlap and become a mess. I'd also suggest that you call `show()` and `hide()` directly on the required elements instead of faking `click` events in the DOM. Try this:

```js
function openBand() {
  $('#yourElement').show();
  setTimeout(closeBand, 50000);
}

function closeBand() {
  $('#yourElement').hide();
  setTimeout(openBand, 15000);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(openBand, 15000);
  // or just call closeBand() here directly, if the element starts as hidden
});
```

Comment: I changed show() and hide()  to trigger the buttons, and it worked fine. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem glad to help

Answer (score 1):

If the code inside the setInterval takes longer than the time you have set it will create another process before the function finishes messing everything up. So choosing setTimeout is actually better.

To make a function loops in setTimeout use a following syntax:

```
function function1() {
    // something here
}

function runner() {
    function1();
    setTimeout(function() {
        runner();
    }, time);
}

runner();
```

Comment: While interesting, it's unlikely to be the case here as setTimeout would take no time to initialise and, given the context, the click likely just calls .show() which wont take 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your current function with this one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(() => {
    $('#open-band').trigger('click');
  }, 15000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#close-band').trigger('click');
  }, 50000);
});
```

Comment: Why? What would this achieve?  It *certainly* won't work after the first setTimeout.